# Can I use grep to pull out a particular pattern from a file / number of files, using regex perhaps?

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I have a file with a load of errors in it. I used grep to pull out all the `JSONExcpetion` Errors and save them in a new file like this:

```
sudo grep -Hrn "JSONException" 2016-* >> jsonexception.txt
```

Now I have a file with a lot of `JSONExceptions` in it. Some of those exceptions contain IDs. I'd like to pull out the ID's and save them to another file.

In my Java code, I use the following regex to identify the correct ID formatting in a `String`:

```
^([A-Fa-f0-9]{24})$
```

Can I use something similar with grep to pull IDs from `jsonexception.txt` and save them to another file?

A sample from the log:

2016-02/server-2016-02-11-3.log:17425:11/Feb/2016 12:08:35,519 [ERROR] [Thread-3] - WorkerRunnable: Worker 2: A JSONException occurred, on the string: {"DEVICE":[{"
ID":"**32584305d2ff32051d06dfff**"},{"TimeStamp":1455185304,"Event":"Boot","BuildDate":"Feb 11 2016","BuildTime":"10:48:00","Reason":"Power on Reset","FSHigh":485,"FSLow":475
,"VerMajor":0,"VerMinor":9,"VerRevision":2,"VerPatch":2,"MAC":"00:06:66:3a:26:5c","WlanVersion":"4.75","WlanModuleType":"RN131","BoardRev":"RevD1","DisinfectSeconds":0},{
"TimeStamp":1455185316,"Event":"CurrentSettings","IssuedTime":0,"FSHigh":535,"FSLow":425,"Duty":100,"Frequency":1000,"Current":80,"IdlePeriod":30,"StillOnPeriod":20,"Auto
OnPeriod":43200,"AutoOnDuration":10,"MaxOnTime":14400,"FlowSensitivity":50,"LidSwitches":1,"UvFluxWarn":70,"UvFluxInsufficient":40,"Firm
Server":"���^A.^B�^B.^P�^K�^G�^C�JF^M�        �H�O�zp^HI����^C�^G�^C�^M�B�^N�^R���    ����O^B�pG�^D","FirmPort:1,"DeviceTypeName":"","WlanTimeZone":25,"LedRegArray":[{"Bo
ardId":"A","LedNo":0,"RegState":"Regulate"},{"BoardId":"A","LedNo":1,"RegState":"Regulate"}]},{"TimeStamp":1455185316,"Event":"CurrentWlanSettings","SettingsArray":[{"WlanSettingsId":1},{"WlanSettingsId":2},{"WlanSettingsId":3}]},{"TimeStamp":145518531
5,"Event":"Connect","WlanSettingsId":1,"MAC":"00:06:66:3a:26:5c","IP":"192.168.1.125","WLAN":"TEST1","RSSI":-52,"Version":"4.75","AP-MAC":"ac:9e:17:ea:0f:3c"},{"End
":100}]}^M

Comment: Can you show a line from the file you want to grep?

Comment: I've added a line above, the ID I want to grep is bolded, it's a 24 char hexadecimal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `grep` supports `-o`, you can use the following:

```
grep -o '"ID":"[a-f0-9]\{24\}"' | cut -d\" -f4
```

The first part extracts only the `"ID":"..."` part, the second one selects the 4th column, using `"` as the separator, i.e. the id itself.

It's much safer to include the `"ID":` in the query, otherwise you can accidentally match a different part of the line.

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me when I used the OP's sample text. However `grep -Eo "(ID\":\"[0-9a-zA-Z]*\")"` did work for me. Might add it to yours as a possible added solution in-case the first fails.